# Most Frequent Word in a Text

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, words

## Task

The parameter here is a filename! The file contains a text. The task of the script is to decide which word is contained most frequently in other words.

---

## Example Input And Output

(e.g. the text is: play ball football basketball snowball - therefore ball is the winner because it is part of three other worlds).

---

## My code sofar

I did this code so far, but it doesn't work for every output

```
!/bin/sh
awk '{for(i=2;i<NF;i++) {s=$i; for(j=i+1;j<=NF;j++) print s=s FS $j}}' $1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1rn -k2 | sed 's/ *[^ ]* *//;q' | cut -f1 -d" "
```

Comment: the most frequent word ..... like ball in the example

Comment: So you're really looking for substrings? Or do you need to validate each substring against a wordlist, just in case a string is not a proper word? The string `a` seems to occur more often than `ball`, and `l` even more often.

Comment: no, if I searched for substrings it will be as u said, but the thing I want to compare between the words themselves, the most word that exists in the other words so basically we should give the word here in the example the word "ball" occur in football, basketball, and snowball so we want to take this word as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list of words is in a file called `words`, with a single word on each line (possibly created with `tr ' ' '\n' <originalwords >words` to split the original list up into multiple lines), then the loop

```
while IFS= read -r word; do
    grep -F -o -e "$word" words
done <words | awk '{ c[$0]++; if (c[$0] > c[w]) w = $0 } END { print w }'
```

will output the word that occurs most times as part of  words in the list (or, if many words occur equally many times, the one of those words that occurred first in the list).

It does this by using the list itself as a set of patterns to match against the list.  With `-o` we ask for matching substrings to be returned on individual lines.

The output of the loop alone, with the list given in the question will be

```
play
ball
ball
ball
ball
football
basketball
snowball
```

It's then just a matter of counting these words and singling out the one that occurs most often.

---

As a complete script, with temporary file handling:

```
#!/bin/sh

tmpfile=$(mktemp)

trap 'rm -f "$tmpfile"' EXIT      # delete temporary file upon exiting

tr -s ' ' '\n' <"${1:-/dev/stdin}" >"$tmpfile"  # convert into word list

while IFS= read -r word; do
    grep -F -o -e "$word" "$tmpfile"
done <"$tmpfile" | awk '{ c[$0]++; if (c[$0] > c[w]) w = $0 } END { print w }'
```

The script additionally reads from standard input if there is no file specified.

Comment: what if i want the input just a single line, would it work?

Comment: @CSpractice You would have to divide it up into lines, possibly by passing it through `tr ' ' '\n'`.

Comment: where i should make the tr command

Comment: tr ' ' '\n' | grep -o -f words words | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | sed 's/.*[[:digit:]] //; q'

Comment: @CSpractice No. You wil have to create the `words` file from the original file like so: `tr ' ' '\n' <original >words`, then you can run the pipeline.

Comment: if you mean the text ... we will write it in another file and take the file as the first parameter

Comment: @CSpractice Or, you can replace the first part of the pipeline with `grep -o -f <(tr ' ' '\n' <original) <(tr ' ' '\n' <original)`. But this requires `bash` or some other shell that understands process substitutions, not `sh`.

Comment: ohh, okay ... thanks 4 your efforts!

Comment: @Kusalananda GNU grep 3.4 is not providing me with the same output for `grep -o -f words words`. It just returns the content of `words` – "ball" is not returned multiple times.

Comment: @guest Hmmm... Odd. Either a bug in GNU `grep` or a nice feature in OpenBSD `grep` (which is what I'm using). I wonder why they accepted the answer?

Comment: @Kusalananda My GNU versions (3.3 Debian/3.4 Homebrew) seem to only match the longest pattern in the pattern file (same result with `grep -o -f words -e 'all' words`) and BSD grep 2.5.1-FreeBSD returns `play` and 4x `ball` :)

Comment: @Kusalananda: I believe that I can clarify the `grep` ‘problem’ a little.  It has nothing to do with `-f` and very little to do with `-o`.  The thing is that GNU `grep` won’t match overlapping strings.  For example, ``echo center | grep 'cent\|enter'`` (or `grep -e cent -e enter`) will match `cent` but not `enter` (as determined by `--color` or `-o`).  Similarly, ``echo catch | grep '[abc]*\|cat'`` will find `cat` and `c` (the second one), but not `ca`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  The rules seem to be: if multiple matching substrings overlap, take the one that begins first, and if multiple matching substrings begin at the same point, take the longest one.  So ``echo football | grep 'ball\|football'`` finds `football` but not `ball`.  After skimming [the GNU Grep 3.4 Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/) and [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) for six to eight minutes, I couldn’t find anything that specified how it would (or should) handle such a case.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Thanks! This makes a bit of sense. Since `-o` is non-standard, the various developers have implemented similar functionality ever so slightly different. Fixed my answer now.

Comment: @guest I turned it into a loop, just to make sense that I got the desired behavior from all `grep` variants.

Comment: (1) Well, this may be a distinction without a difference, but I still say that it’s not an issue with the implementation of ``-o``, *per se.*  [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) says “if any pattern … (BRE) … matches any part of the line”, “If any entire ERE pattern matches some part of an input line” and “selected lines shall be those that match any of the specified patterns”, so it seems to be bending over backwards to avoid saying that `grep` matches strings.  And, as we know (I believe that it’s been discussed here before),  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  `echo aardvark | grep -c 'a'` outputs `1`, not `3`.  `grep` matches *lines*; it (at the POSIX level) doesn’t have a *concept* of matching strings.  (But I’d be curious to see what `echo aardvark | grep -c 'a'` and `echo aardvark | grep -c -o 'a'` do on OpenBSD.)  (2) Your solution fails for this edge case: `ball ball football snowball ant advantage byzantine chrysanthemum giant lantern panther`, because, while `ant` matches seven words and `ball` matches only four, those four get counted twice. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) I dislike UUOC as much as the next person, but ISTM that a pipeline that begins with `tr` provides decent justification for saying `cat "$@" |`.  (4) Yesterday, I started to write a comment asking the OP to clarify the question.  Here’s an edge case that I didn’t even think of then: given the input ```ball football hardball softball snowball e teleconference```, should the answer be `ball` (which appears in five words) or `e` (which appears six *times*)?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                uwords[$i] = 0
                allwords[++idx] = $i
        }
     }
    END {
                if (idx == 0) exit
                max = 0
                for (w in uwords) {
                        count = 0
                        for (i=1; i<=idx; i++) {
                                if (allwords[i] ~ w) count++;
                        }
                        if (count > max) {
                                max = count
                                maxw = w
                        }
                }
                print maxw
        }'
```

Scan the input and extract a list of unique words and a list of all words. 
(I guess we don’t need the list of unique words,
but it may make things more efficient in the case of a large input.) 
Then, for each unique word, count how many words in the file match it. 
(So, if the file contains `football football football`,
that counts 3 toward `ball`.) 
Keep track of the one with the most matches.

In case of a tie,
it reports the word that appears first in the `uwords` (unique words) array. 
This is not necessarily the first one that appears in the file,
nor is it the alphabetically first.

This may produce unexpected results
if any of the words contain **`.`**, `*` or `[`.

---

If you prefer Kusalananda’s shell+awk approach,
but don’t want the edge case error, do this:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

trap 'rm -f "$tmpfile"' EXIT      # delete temporary file upon exiting

tr -s ' ' '\n' < "${1:-/dev/stdin}" > "$tmpfile"  # convert into word list

sort -u "$tmpfile" | while IFS= read -r word
do
    grep -F -o -e "$word" "$tmpfile"
done | awk '{ c[$0]++; if (c[$0] > c[w]) w = $0 } END { print w }'
```

By sorting the word list, we get a list of unique words,
and thereby don’t count any words multiple times.

Note that this code explicitly assumes
that there is at most one input file
(but there could be no file; i.e., read from stdin). 
This is consistent with the phrasing of the question. 
However, if there may be any number of input files (zero, one, *or more*),
change the `tr` line to

```
cat -- "$@" | tr -s ' ' '\n' > "$tmpfile"         # convert into word list
```

Arguably it’s a UUOC, but

- it handles the case of two or more input files, and
- it’s more readable than `< "${1:-/dev/stdin}"`.

Comment: Hi, it would be possible to use index function `index(allwords[i], w)` instead of regex matching `allwords[i] ~ w`

Comment: Yes, it certainly would.  In fact, I considered using it; I stuck with `~` because it was shorter and I didn’t want to bother explaining why I used `index`.